# Numpy attributes not recognized in Numba

Tags: python, numpy

Numba offers JIT for Python. In its documentation it says "One objective of Numba is having a seamless integration with NumPy."

So why including some of the simplest features from numpy isn't possible:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import *

@jit(nopython=True)
def testfun(x):
     y = np.size(x)
     return y

x=np.array([1 ,2, 3],dtype=float)
testfun(x)
```

When I run this code, I get the error "Unknown attribute 'size' of type Module."

Numba understands calls to NumPy ufuncs. I assume simple numpy functions such  as size, shape, sum, reshape, etc are ufuncs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it is not supported, but this works:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import *

@jit(nopython=True)
def testfun(x):
     y = x.size
     return y

x=np.array([1 ,2, 3],dtype=float)
testfun(x)
```

You might want to have a look at the Supported NumPy features on their web-site.